# Highly strange deletion

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Earlier this year (or possibly last year), I wrote a Q about Windows Media Center, which randomly changes the language of descriptions of recorded media (TV):

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [rejbrand.se](http://privat.rejbrand.se/WMCdescrlangerror.png))</sub>

**The description used to be in Swedish before WMC changed the language to some other language, probably Finnish.**

Since I can no longer find that Q, I suppose it has been deleted. Why is that? Is it not allowed to point out (apparent) bugs in Microsoft software, and ask for solutions and work-arounds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [question you asked is here](https://superuser.com/questions/476232/windows-media-center-spontaneously-changing-the-language-of-program-descriptions). It was automatically deleted because it fell under the criteria explained [in this Meta Stack Overflow post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/159624).

Basically, it didn't get enough votes or views.

I undeleted it for you—doesn't seem like a bad question at all.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and undeletion!